# Reading Serial gives ascii conversion of Hexadecimals

Tags: python-2.7, communication, pyserial, uart

I am reading serial data using pyserial in Python 2.7
Data is as follows:

```
static uint8_t dataArray[] =
{

0x01, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0xf1, 0xa9, 0xc3, 0x03,
0x1c, 0x02, 0xe1, 0xb2, 0x3f, 0x50, 0x7d, 0xfe,
0x7e, 0x3e, 0x8e, 0x1f, 0x91, 0x1d, 0x80, 0xd1,
0x67, 0x5b, 0x8f, 0x5f, 0x50, 0x53, 0xcd, 0xf1,
0x7b, 0xa8, 0x46, 0x73, 0x9e, 0x31, 0xf1, 0x93,
0x65, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x27, 0xc3, 0xec, 0x6d, 0x81,
0x2e, 0xa7, 0x8b, 0x15, 0x51, 0x61, 0xdc, 0x5f,
0xa1, 0x1a, 0xd9, 0xf6, 0x50, 0xac, 0x2b, 0x33,
0x3c,0x23
};
```

Now when I try to read it in python. it gets received there as ascii conversion of the each byte.
The python code is as follows:

```
uart= serial.Serial()
uart.baudrate= 19200
uart.port = 'COM8'
uart.parity= serial.PARITY_NONE
uart.bytesize= serial.EIGHTBITS
uart.stopbits= serial.STOPBITS_ONE
uart.timeout = 40 
if(uart.is_open!=1):
    uart.open()

 while uart.is_open:


        byte = uart.read(1) #Read one byte in each iteration
        if(byte):
            #dencoded_byte = byte.decode('Ascii')
            dencoded_byte = byte.decode('utf-8')
            print dencoded_byte
```

Output I get before getting exception

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

is as follows:

```
utf-8
1
1
1
```

I have tried using `byte.decode('Ascii')` that also gets exception when incoming data is larger than 128 (it also does not translate that data as it was send too, only gives ascii again)also tried converting to int etc but with no success.

Can anybody suggest some simple solution which can enable me to read any byte coming from the uart up to its maximum that is 256= 2^8
and also I should be able to write it in the form of numbers or as it is send in from serial? For example the first hex number send from serial is 0x01 in array - I want to print same in the python program.

Comment: Using `latin-1` instead of `ascii` should let you receive any arbitrary byte. Moving to Python 3 would somewhat clarify the situation, though not necessarily simplify it (but there are many other good reasons to abandon Python 2 already anyway).

Comment: A utf-8 character can be longer than one byte! If you want to read utf-8, be prepared to read more than one byte. If you do just want to read the numbers, do not convert them to utf-8. Why don’t you just leave the bytes as-is if you just want the bytes?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This data is clearly not UTF-8.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed. I do not think any encoding is appropriate, but if one insists on using one it should be done properly at least.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number corresponding to each 1-byte string, use `ord`:

```
    if(byte):
        byte_num = ord(byte)
        print byte_num
```

If you were using Python 3, there would be an alternative solution, as `bytes` instances can be indexed to get numeric values, so `byte[0]` would be the same as calling `ord(byte)`.

Of course, in Python 2, the byte you received is already a `str` instance, since there's no distinguishing between bytes and 8-bit strings in that version of Python (your `decode` calls, when they work, return `unicode` instances). So maybe a solution is not to try to decode the byte at all, and just to print it out raw, as it were: `print byte`. I'm not sure this would be wise, as printing some control characters might mess up your console. But it's probably a more reasonable option if you're going to do something other than print your data, like storing it in some kind of data structure.

Comment: Hi @blckknght thank you for your input .It does not give required results. when I try that it gives following:
    >>ord('0x66')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found
     >>ord(0x66)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 4, line 1
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
     >>ord('c')
99                                          
Which shows it expects only a character of ascii upto 128.

Comment: I have discovered one partial solution i.e as follows:
                  dencoded_asci_byte = byte.decode('cp437')
                  dencoded_byte = dencoded_asci_byte.encode('hex')
                  print dencoded_byte
It generated most of the hex values send but some of them are appearing as more than a byte i.e either corrupted or picking up two bytes too.
for example i have one printed byte as: e28c90 
which seems like a 3 bytes combination printed together

Comment: @AMaq Escape sequences are formed like "\x66". The 0x is only for integers, similar to 0b.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your responses.

Finally, managed to resolve the problem.Simply by using following :

```
#these **first three lines are for only python2** 
#as Python 3 is default utf-8  
import sys

reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

dencoded_byte = byte.encode('hex')
```

instead of :

```
dencoded_byte = byte.decode('utf-8')
```